# AS3 event.target and var

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an editable text field (c) in a movieClip, well 3 movielips like this actually named a1, a2 and a3. Movieclips are already on stage. The path to text field in each MC is mc.a1.c, mc.a2.c and mc.a3.c
The initial value for each textfield is set by XML which is also stored in variables with the same names and the movieclip(a1,a2,a3). If the user updates a textfield a CHANGE event listener triggers checkValue function. If the value is greater than my maxValue I want my function to return the text field to its original value and give the user an error message. So if textfield c in mc.a1.c is updated, I'm currently taking the name of its parent (a1) and then trying to reference the variable with the same name so that textfield c will be returned to the initial value held in var a1 (I'll only know which var to reference once a textfield update has been attempted.. hope that makes sense)

I've tried several things but always end up with the variable name, and not its value in the textfield. So, for now I've reverted to populating the field with 0 until I can find an answer.

example code:
aH.t1 is the predefined max value

```
function chngTh(event:Event):void{
    var thR:String = String(event.target.parent.name.substring(0,1));
    if  (thR =="a"&&thN>int(aH.t1.text)){
        event.target.text = 0; //I want the reference var a(x)and have its value in the text field
        aH.errorMsg.text = "The number cannot be greater than 10 so the original value has been restored";
                }
}
```

As you can probably tell my my code, I'm not a developer and I've already looked here in search of but can't seem to get grasp it...Is it me?

[reference variable AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373291/reference-variable-as3)

[AS3: Using string as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681051/as3-using-string-as-variable#10681594)

Is what I'm trying to do achiveable in AS3?

Thanks to guidance from dene the solution looks like this:

```
function chngTh(event:Event):void{
            var thR:String = String(event.target.parent.name.substring(0,1));
            var thN:int = (event.target.text);
            var thov:int = root[event.target.parent.name];

            if  (thR =="a"&&thN>int(aH.thrsh.t1.text)){
                event.target.text = thov;
                aH.errorMsg.text = hclbl[12];
                }
       }
```

Comment: Can you please post your code here? How do you create the movie clips?

Comment: Please take a look at this example, maybe it will help: http://wonderfl.net/c/40oB

Comment: @Nibooo Thanks for the response.Movieclips are already on stage. I could create them dynamically but at present I don't. I've updated my question with some code but as you can probably see I'm not a developer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `event.target` in the listener function to reference the text field that changed:

```
var maxValue = 5;

myTextField.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, textListener);

function textListener(event:Event)
{
    var tf = event.target as TextField;
    var currentValue = parseFloat(tf.text);

    if (currentValue > maxValue) {
        tf.text = getOriginalValue(tf);
    }
}

function getOriginalValue(tf:TextField) : Number
{
    // Assuming the textfield's parent is named "a" + number (eg. a1, a2 etc.)
    // Get the number of the parent by ignoring the character at index 0
    var parentName = tf.parent.name;
    var parentNumber = parentName.substring(1);

    // Now you can use parentNumber to access the associated variable (a1, a2, etc)
    // Assuming these variables are defined on the root (main timeline).
    var originalValue = root["a" + parentNumber]
    // If the variables are stored as Strings, this line is needed to convert it to a Number type
    originalValue = parseFloat(originalValue)

    return originalValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but... populating the  text filed with the max value is not what I'm trying to achieve. I want to be able to restore the original value which is already held in a variable. Unfortunately, I have three vars corresponding to the inital values of the 3 text fields and I won't know which field is being updated until the user selects hence my snippet:- event.target.text = 0; //I want the value of var a(x) to be here

Comment: Thanks again. Your update was closer to my problem but as you see I already have the xml stored in vars a1,a2,a3. What I'm trying to do is match the parent movieClip with the var...So if the parent is a1 I want to be able to reference the var a1 and populate the text field with its value... does that make sense?

Comment: I've updated the answer. The important line is `var originalValue = root["a" + parentNumber]`. This assumes the "a" variables are defined on the root timeline.

Comment: That was it...Doh! I feel so stupid now... I tried everything but root... thanks, works like a charm